# Java program to describe SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql-server

i am trying to write Java program to describe SQL Server Stored procedure. here i have only input is Stored procedure name, from that i need to get SP parameters and Return types and those lengths..

can anybody helpme out..

Comment: Look at [StoredProcedure](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.5/api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html).

Comment: What you have tried. just write your research and program.

Answer (score 0):

get SP name from `dbo.sysobjects` table

get SP parameters/columns from `dbo.syscolumns` table.

```
use pubs

-- list all stored procedures 列出所有存储过程
select * from dbo.sysobjects where OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1

-- get parameters/columns of stored procedure 'dt_checkinobject' 获取存储过程'dt_checkinobject'的所有参数
select *
from
    dbo.syscolumns c
    join dbo.sysobjects o  on c.id=o.id
where
    1=1
    and OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, N'IsProcedure') = 1
    and.o.name='dt_checkinobject'
```